# How to specify zookeeper info while instantiating apache storm LocalCluster

Tags: local, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I want to instantiate a LocalCluster() and prevent it from runing its own embedded zookeeper, and use mine instead.

Regarding to this issue : "https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-213" it is resolved for version 0.9.3.

can I have a sample code for this?

PS: I am integrate testing my storm topology, and I use kafka and zookeeper as input to storm.
when i don't specify the zookeeper info to localcluster, i get this exception at line "LocalCluster localCluster = new LocalCluster()":

```
2016-06-08 12:16:56,785 WARN  [Thread-30] jmx.MBeanRegistry (MBeanRegistry.java:register(100)) - Failed to register MBean StandaloneServer_port-1
2016-06-08 12:16:56,785 WARN  [Thread-30] server.ZooKeeperServer (ZooKeeperServer.java:registerJMX(387)) - Failed to register with JMX
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.ZooKeeperService:name0=StandaloneServer_port-1
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.jmx.MBeanRegistry.register(MBeanRegistry.java:96)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.registerJMX(ZooKeeperServer.java:377)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.startup(ZooKeeperServer.java:410)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.startup(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:123)
```

and when I specify "storm.zookeeper.servers" and "storm.zookeeper.port" to local cluster, I get below exception at "localCluster.submitTopology()" line:

```
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1552f0890b70000, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:26)
    at org.apache.storm.testing$submit_local_topology.invoke(testing.clj:301)
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster$_submitTopology.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:49)
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster.submitTopology(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I think, it is sufficient to specify "storm.zookeeper.servers" property in your Config that you hand to LocalCluster to make it work.

Comment: tanx for your reply, I did it, and also set "storm.zookeeper.port" but when I submit the topology, I get a NullPointerException! without any more detail!

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overload `LocalCluster` constructor.

```
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster("localhost", 2181L);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Kafka as the input of an Storm topology by using the configuration provided at this link http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/storm-kafka.html

I created a specific java class for the storm config

```
public class StormConfig {

private String zooKeeperConnect;

public StormConfig() {

}
public KafkaSpout getkafkaSpout(String topic){
    return new KafkaSpout(this.getSpoutConfig(topic));
}

public SpoutConfig getSpoutConfig(String topic) {
    SpoutConfig spoutConfig=new SpoutConfig(this.getZkHosts(), topic, "", topic);
    spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    spoutConfig.startOffsetTime=kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime();
    return spoutConfig;
}

public ZkHosts getZkHosts() {
    return new ZkHosts(getZooKeeperConnect());
}

public String getZooKeeperConnect() {
    return zooKeeperConnect;
}

public void setZooKeeperConnect(String zooKeeperConnect) {
    this.zooKeeperConnect = zooKeeperConnect;
}
}
```

Then I used the method from this class when creating the initial spout of the topology:

```
builder.setSpout("kafkaSpoutName", stormConfig.getkafkaSpout("topicName"))
            .setNumTasks(Constants.SPOUT_NUM_TASKS);
```